# Use a passed variable in an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm passing two variables to my front end like this

```
res.render("mypage", {data: data});
```

Using the data within my variable, I want to build some HTML elements and do some data visualization using charts. I can of course just use my templating software (EJS) and write a whole lot of javascript within the HTML file itself, but that doesn't sound sensible.

I searched around stackoverflow and the general solution seems to be to put it into a global variable and then load in the external js file so it has access to it, so on my front end I would have this

```
    <head>
        <title>Cool Site</title>
        <script>
            var data = <%- data %>;
        </script>
        <script src="/fun.js"></script>
    </head>
```

The problem is that VSCode itself says `Expression Expected` for my `<%-` and `%>` parts, and when I try to access the variable within my `fun.js` file, it says `Data is not defined` and also says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.

Any ideas on how I can properly access the data?

Comment: is your document file extention .ejs ?

Comment: Does `<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>` work? Otherwise, your script tag may contain something like `var data = [Object object];`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using EJS and loading small data (like name) in other areas on the page and it works fine. I imagine the problem is with me trying to set a variable equal to an EJS thing

Comment: You should share what your HTML looks like (view source), especially that script block.

Comment: @Jacob Well damn... It does work. I'm still getting an error on the editor I'm using but it seems to be working fine and I can access it from the back end. Any idea why it was throwing errors before?

Comment: Will put in an answer.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS is simply a templating language. It spits out text. It will interpret the following:

```
<script>
  var data = <%- data %>;
</script>
```

...sort of like:

```
`<script>
  var data = ${data};
</script>`
```

So what does `<%- data %>` mean? It means take the raw value of the expression and output it to the result. Since `data` is an Object, it's most likely calling `toString` on it, and `.toString()` for an Object by default is the string `[Object object]`, making your JavaScript the following, which has a syntax error:

```
<script>
  var data = [Object object];
</script>
```

Your easiest workaround would be to *serialize* your data as JSON, which is intepretable within JavaScript as an object literal:

```
<script>
  var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
</script>
```

...though you do have to be careful about edge conditions like where your data may contain a `</script>` string, in which case it'll prematurely close your script tag. Fortunately there are many packages out there for a safer version of JSON stringifying for output on an HTML page. Use a safer stringifying library if your data can contain arbitrary user strings; otherwise you've got a script injection vulnerability.

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot of sense. And thanks for pointing out the thing about script injection vulnerability. The data doesn't have any user inputted strings so I should be good on that front but I may use one just in case? Either way thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, doesn't hurt to use one anyway.